# Term Filter for Value with Slash without Mapping in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, lucene, special-characters, slash

I have a requirement where I cannot add any mapping to ElasticSearch index since all indices are dynamic and get created at run-time and all have different fields (with only 5 common ones). Because of that I'm having an issues using term filter for URL (e.g. http://www.domain.com/a/b) or mimetype (e.g. image/jpeg). What is the best way to get around slashes or other special characters without adding mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on the answer by @tcarmet, This is what I ended up using for the template.

```
{
    "enable_raw_string": {
        "order": 0,
        "template": "*",
        "settings": {},
        "mappings": {
          "_default_": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
              {
                "strings": {
                  "mapping": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "fields": {
                      "raw": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "match_mapping_type": "string"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "aliases": {}
      }
}
```

Then I can just filter against x.raw instead of x.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a template to your elasticsearch index

There you can specify your index and mapping will be created automatically at run time for all your data.

Comment: How can I use a template if I never know what fields will be added to the index? There are only 5 common fields for the indices and the rest are all different.

Comment: Normally templates can generate multiple fields without specifying his name. They can be generated automatically.

Comment: But how does it know what mapping to use? If I have 20 fields, there is no way to determine whether it should be analyzed or not_analyzed, right? Currently, we are relying on the default mapping by ElasticSearch, which gets it right 95% of the time. I know for query you can specify an analyzer in the request, but I didn't see a way to do the same thing for filter.